# Quiero seguir añadiendo contenido debajo de la imágen del Header

Tags: html, css

He creado un menú responsive y he añadido una imagen para el Header, el problema es que quiero seguir creando mas contenido debajo pero me sale todo dentro del Header, en el html esta bien todo, me imagino que debería cambiar algo del CSS dejo unas imágenes de como se ve y el código, gracias =) Ese: 'Hola' quiero que aparezca debajo del header..[image: quiero poner ese HOLA debajo de la imagen del Header]

```css
body{
   font-family: var(--fuenteParrafos);
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 1.6rem;
   line-height: 1.6;
   background: url(img/hero.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
 <div class="contenedor">
        <main class="main">
            <h1>HOLA</h1>
        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ismael, para poder ayudarte necesitamos más información; específicamente tu HTML completo y si estas usando alguna librería tipo Bootstrap

Comment: El ejemplo que publicaste, por supuesto, no se parece en nada a la imagen que produce tu código real. Te invito a preparar un [mcve], eso mejorará las probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que muestras en tu código CSS la imagen de fondo se las has dado al body y no al header, Y como has usado la propiedad background, esta imagen se colocará como fondo de todo tu contenido en el body. Por lo que interpreto no nos has compartido la totalidad del html, y al no saber donde está ubicado el elemento div que contiene tu h1 es dificil poder ayudarte.